# Highlighting HTML table when a link in the table is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a lengthy asp.net page. A HTML table in the page has a link. when the link is clicked the page refreshes and takes me to the top part of the page. Instead, i want to see the part of the page that has the link. It should automatically scroll down to that part once the page refreshes. How is that possible.

Really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET 2.0 or above, and that is a LinkButton doing a postback, you can use:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add  `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True"` in the page directive.

Answer (score 0):

To color a row you can do this by using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and by using a unique ID per table row, you can do:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr");
var linkRow = rows.FirstOrDefault(node =>
{
    HtmlAttribute a = node.Attributes["id"];
    if (null == a) return false;
    return "idLookingFor" == a.Value;
});
linkRow.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "red");
```